# How to create new EC2 instance with existing EC2 instance image while it is terminating?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have used Elastic Beanstalk for creating the EC2 instances. Is it possible to screate the new EC2 instance with the existing EC2 instance image, when the existing EC2 instance is getting terminated in any case? Can we achieve this by any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.
As soon as you send a terminate request on your EC2 instance, the IP and hardware (disk and other resources) are released.

If you are trying to do this programmatically, I'd suggest you create an AMI before sending a terminate request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AMI from the EC2 before you terminate it, and then create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment using this AMI. However, it's not advisable as you'll lose future version upgrades of that AMI as performed by Amazon.
I advise you use the `.ebextensions` folder mechanism supplied by Elastic Beanstalk in order to alter new instances as they are spawned (see [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)).